# making new directory in perl

Tags: perl, directory

I want to create a directory with a certain name before the beginning of a method. At each iteration the directory should be replaced with new entries instead of getting appended.

I have used this code:

```
sub makingDirectoryForClient {
    $nameOfTheClientDirectory = $_[0];
    my $directory = "D:\\ATEF\\clientfolder\\$nameOfTheClientDirectory";
    my $outputvar = mkdir $directory;
}
```

but still the folder is not getting replaced. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Are you saying that `mkdir` doesn't create a directory?

Comment: Do you have access for this folder site?

Comment: If a directory already exists `mkdir` does nothing. If you want an existing directory removed you have to do that yourself.

Comment: What do you meant "the directory should be replaced"? Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: @dgw ohhhhh! i understood now!! thankyou so much :)

Comment: @Meghna: Okay, then please would you write up an answer for your own question: we need to resolve this somehow. It may not feel like it, but the primary point of any *Stack Overflow* page is for the rest of the world with a similar problem, not for the original poster.

Comment: @Borodin yeah sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mkdir` appears to be doing nothing then you should code a warning statement to find out why. The reason for failure will be in built-in variable `$!`, so I suggest you write your subroutine like this

```
sub make_client_dir {
    my $client_dir = shift;

    my $path = "D:\\ATEF\\clientfolder\\$client_dir";

    ( my $success = mkdir $path ) or
            warn qq{Unable to create directory "$path": $!};

    return $success;
}
```

Note that I've also modified your code to be more idiomatic

Comment: @Dada: Of course I did. How embarrassing! Thank you. Can I blame a sleepless night?

Comment: I was wondering if it was the lack of sleep or someone who switched the `_` and the `!` on your keyboard; I now have my answer :D

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer but i had some other problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create a directory of the same name that already existed since I thought that would replace the folder with a new empty folder. But Perl does not work that way: `mkdir` will not work if a folder of the same name already exists.

So I first deleted the directory using `rmtree` from `File::Path` and then created a new directory of the same name.

Comment: It's not just Perl that works like that: every file system I know will not let you overwrite an existing directory with an empty one. I understand your confusion because opening a new file works differently.

Comment: @Borodin oh! okay! Thank you so  much!